# Python 3.2 save unicode chars to file from background program

Tags: python, unicode

I am running a python script from my /etc/rc.local on a Raspberry Pi. My script runs a web server that takes incoming file names from POST. Sometimes these file names have non-ascii characters such as õäöü. The problem is that if I try to write this to a file, I get `UnicodeEncodeError` / `UnicodeDecodeError` depending on if I try to write it as `bytes` or `str`.

This only happens if I try to run it from start, if I ssh in and try running it, everything is fine.

I can't print out the string I am trying to save either, I always get a `UnicodeEncodeError`: 'ascii' coded.. error since the shell is in ascii.

My code to save:

```
def save(self, filePaths):#filePaths is a list of str
    playlistContents = '[playlist]\n'
    playlistContents += 'NumberOfEntries='+str(len(filePaths))+'\n'

    for i in range(len(filePaths)):
        #if i do ascii(filePaths[i]) then I get a str which saves but obviously is wrong
        playlistContents += 'File'+str((i + 1))+'='+Playlist.escapeFilePath(filePaths[i])+'\n'

    fileHandler = open(self.path, 'w+')#or 'wb'
    fileHandler.write(playlistContents)#if wb, then 'playlistContents.encode()'
    fileHandler.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, Python assumes that all filenames are encoded according to the setting reported by [`sys.getfilesystemencoding()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.getfilesystemencoding) . However, certain filesystems don’t necessarily enforce this encoding restriction, thereby al
lowing files to be created without proper filename encoding. So you need to encode your file names . you can use the following function to do it (with change from *Python Cookbook, 3rd Edition* by *David Beazley and Brian K. Jones*) :

```
def bad_filename(filename):   
    temp=filename.encode(sys.getfilesystemencoding(),errors='surrogateescape')
    return temp.decode('latin-1')
```

Also you can use `repr` :

```
def bad_filename(filename):
     return repr(filename)[1:-1]


try:
    print(filename)
except UnicodeEncodeError:
    print(bad_filename(filename))
```

> **sys.getfilesystemencoding()** Return the name of the encoding used to
>   convert Unicode filenames into system file names, or None if the
>   system default encoding is used.

Comment: Neither of those work. Both cause a `UnicodeDecodeError` ascii codec cant encode character... error.

Comment: @shiznatix did you convert your path to unicode ? you can use `unicode(path,'escape-unicode')`